# Print array of sheets to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that prints the active sheet to PDF and names it based on cell values. I want to print two sheets into a single file. (If separate files, that is OK.)

The cell value naming can be changed at the top which I can do. It is calling for the export to pdf that I'm having an issue with.

I tried calling for a sheet array, but it doesn't like the `exportasfixedformat Type:=`. It likes it in the original code, but not when I change the `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.

```vb
Sub GetFilePath_Click()
 
Dim FileAndLocation As Variant
Dim strFilename As String

strFilename = Sheets("Leave Loading").Range("F13") & ", " & Sheets("Leave Loading").Range("F12") & " - " & Sheets("Leave Loading").Range("F14") & "- " & "Leave Loading" & ".pdf"

FileAndLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
  (InitialFileName:=strPathLocation & strFilename, _
  filefilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
  Title:="Select a Location to Save")

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFilename, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you heaps! its working a treat. I just have a small question if i can? Its exporting to PDF which is great, but its over-riding the file if there is something with the same name (this is on a separate tab for HDA) when it exports it just saves over the previous one. Is there a way i can get it to recognised that a file already exists with that name? Like how the windows save as function works, where if a file by that name exists, i can choose to add something to the end (like 1,2,3 etc)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GetFilePath_Click()
 
    Dim FileAndLocation As Variant
    Dim strFilename As String, strPathLocation As String
    
    strPathLocation = ""
    With Sheets("Leave Loading")
        strFilename = .Range("F13") & ", " & .Range("F12") & " - " _
                    & .Range("F14") & "- Leave Loading" & ".pdf"
    End With
     
    FileAndLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathLocation & strFilename, _
    filefilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select a Location to Save")
    
    Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet4")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFilename, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```